# The most general form of the metric for a homogeneous, isotropic and static space-time

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

What is the most general form of the metric for a homogeneous, isotropic and static space-time?

For the first 2 criteria, the Robertson-Walker metric springs to mind. (I shall adopt the (-+++) signature)
$$ds^2=dt^2+a^2(t)g_{ij}(\vec x)dx^idx^j$$

Now the static condition. If I'm not mistaken, it means that the metric must be time-independent and invariant under time reversal $t\to -t$. So does that mean that the most general metric that satisfies all these 3 criteria is $$ds^2=dt^2+g_{ij}(\vec x)dx^idx^j$$ for some spatial metric $g_{ij}(\vec x)$?

Thank you.

(My apologies for the mistaken definition. I may have misunderstood what's been said in class...)

Comment: Staticity isn't defined in terms of $t\rightarrow -t$. GR doesn't have any notion of time-reversal that applies to all spacetimes. A spacetime doesn't even have to be time-orientable.

Comment: Thanks, @BenCrowell . So is it just equivalent to stationary...?

Comment: Questions on stackexchange are expected to show research effort. If you need to know the definition of staticity, look it up.

Comment: The time reversal criterion is given in class. That's why I thought it was true!

Comment: Time-reversal only makes sense in some spacetimes. Maybe your professor had in mind some more specific context. Wikipedia defines staticity correctly for the general case: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_spacetime

Comment: When your professor says that the metric has to be time-independent, that doesn't quite make sense. Time-independence of the metric isn't a property of the spacetime. What is a property of the spacetime is if it has a timelike Killing vector. Such a spacetime is called stationary. Given that it's stationary, it's guaranteed to be time-orientable, and it probably makes sense to talk about global time-reversal, although it's not obvious to me why one should be able to cover all of spacetime with one patch. The additional condition of invariance under time-reversal would make it static.

Comment: So in general I think the problem may be that your professor is using coordinate-dependent definitions that just don't quite work. Maybe the intention is to make things easier, but it's coming at the expense of correctness. Sorry for my snippy tone earlier. I downvoted your question because of the incorrect definition, but since the definition came from your professor that was obviously a little harsh. If you make any edit to your question (even a trivial one), the software will let me undo my downvote.

Comment: Another possibility for ungarbling these definitions would be to add an existential quantifier, e.g., "A spacetime is stationary if *there exist* coordinates such that ..."

Answer (score 2):

The FLRW metric can be static, this is the solution that Einstein concocted before Hubble observed the expansion of the universe. The only way that Einstein could make his equations static was by introducing the infamous cosmological constant $\Lambda$. The general FLRW metric has the form
$$
\text{d}s^2 = -c^2\text{d}t^2 + a^2(t)\left[\frac{\text{d}r^2}{1 - kr^2} + r^2\text{d}\theta^2 + r^2\!\sin^2\!\theta\,\text{d}\varphi^2\right],
$$
where $k=-1$, $0$, or $1$ is the curvature of space. The [Einstein field equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) reduce to the **Friedmann equations**
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{a}^2 + kc^2 -\frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}\!a^2 &= \frac{8\pi G}{3}\!\rho\, a^2,\\
2\ddot{a}a + \dot{a}^2 + kc^2 -\Lambda c^2a^2 &= -\frac{8\pi G}{c^2}\!P\,a^2,
\end{align}
$$
with $\rho$ and $P$ the mass density and pressure density. For ordinary matter, $P=0$, and for a static universe we have $\dot{a}=\ddot{a}=0$, so that
$$
\begin{align}
\rho &= \frac{kc^2}{4\pi G a^2},\\
\Lambda &= \frac{k}{a^2}.
\end{align}
$$
moreover, since $\rho > 0$, it follows that $k=1$. In other words, the static universe has the topology of a 3-sphere. It is an unstable solution though: a small value of $\dot{a}$ or $\ddot{a}$ would make it expand or contract. And of course, since Hubble's observations, we know that the universe is in fact expanding.